# How to display a field in tree view based on a selection field value in Odoo?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I have a scenario where a field has to be displayed based on value of the selection field.

```
class mro_order(osv.osv):
_inherit="mro.order"

 _columns={
        'released_part':fields.one2many('mro.released', 'released_id', 'Released parts',),
        'rel_id':fields.many2one('mro.released', 'Parts'),
        'parts_id1': fields.many2one('product.product', 'Parts', required=True, domain = [('maintain_ok','=',True)],),

    }

class mro_order_parts_line(osv.osv):



_inherit="mro.order.parts.line"

    _columns={
        'sts': fields.selection([
        ('new', 'New'),
        ('release', 'released'),

        ], 'State', default='new', readonly= False, select=True),
    }

    def onchange_sts(self, cr, uid, ids, sts):

            value = {}
            if sts == 'release':
                    value['parts_id'] = fields.many2one('mro.released','Parts')
            return value


class mro_released(osv.Model):
    _name="mro.released"

    _columns={
        'name': fields.char('Description', size=64),
            'parts_id': fields.char('Parts'),
            'parts_qty': fields.float('Quantity'),
            'parts_uom': fields.many2one('product.uom','Unit of Measure'),
            'released_id': fields.many2one('mro.order', 'Maintenance Order'),
        'state': fields.selection([
        ('scrap', 'Scrap'),
        ('reusable', 'Re-usable'),

        ], 'State', readonly= False, select=True, required=True),

    }



This is my xml file

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="released_parts_id">
                <field name="name">mro.order.form</field>
                <field name="model">mro.order</field>
                <field name="inherit_id" ref="mro.mro_order_form_view"/>
                <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//form/sheet/notebook/page/group/field/tree/field[@name='parts_id']" position="before">
                <field name="sts" onchange="onchange_sts(sts)"/>
            </xpath>

            <xpath expr="//form/sheet/notebook/page/group[@string='Planned Parts']" position="after">
                            <group string="Released Parts">
                                        <field name="released_part" nolabel="1">

                                            <tree string="Released Parts" editable="bottom">
                                                <field name="parts_id" />
                                                <field name="parts_qty"/>
                                                <field name="parts_uom" />
                                                <field name="name"/>
                                            </tree>


                                        </field>
                                </group>

                    </xpath>
                </field>
            </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Based on the value of selection field, I want to change the relation of a many2one field or based on the value of selection field replace another many2one field named 'A' with different relation to replace the other many2one field named 'B' with different relation in the tree view of xml.

Kindly anyone has any idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **attrs** attribute  for this.

**attrs**

dynamic attributes based on record values.

A mapping of attributes to domains, domains are evaluated in the context of the current row's record, if True the corresponding attribute is set on the cell.

Possible attributes are **invisible** (hides the button) and **readonly** (disables the button but still shows it)

Here for this define two fields separately and give the correct **attrs** attribute to view the correct one.

For Eg:- you can give **attrs** attribute like the following for the field you want to show when the selection field is **"new"**

```
attrs="{'invisible':[('sts', '!=', 'new')]}"
```

From the comments:- code for your condtion

```
                <field name="parts_id1" attrs="{'invisible':[('sts', '!=', 'new')]}"/>
                <field name="parts_id2" attrs="{'invisible':[('sts', '!=', 'release')]}"/>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Baiju, thanks for the answer, but i wanted something like as following :         <xpath expr="//form/sheet/notebook/page/group/field/tree/field[@name='parts_id']" position="replace">
                <field name="parts_id1"  attrs="{'invisible':[('sts', '!=', 'new')]}"/>
            </xpath>
            <xpath expr="//form/sheet/notebook/page/group/field/tree/field[@name='parts_id1']" position="replace">
                <field name="parts_id2" attrs="{'invisible':[('sts', '!=', 'release')]}"/>
            </xpath>

Comment: display a field based on one condition that is parts_id1 or display parts_id 2

Comment: sorry, did you mean you got the answer?

Comment: which are the fields you want to switch?

Comment: parts_id1 and parts_id2 are the two fields , i need to replace parts_id based on the condition

Comment: And what's d condition?

Comment: sts is a selection field , so i want to make parts_id1 invisible when sts field value is release and vice versa

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96793/discussion-between-baiju-ks-and-shravya-shetty).

Comment: there is no need to replace the field using xpath, because we are giving the invisible attribute condition like, at a time only one field is visible. So it working as per your requirement. you have to replace the fields code with the above code.